# How to divide two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've two DataFrames:

```
     info_1  info_2
key                
A         1       6
B         2       7
C         3       8
D         4       9
E         5       0
```

and:

```
     info_3
key        
A         1
B         7
C         3
D         9
E         5
```

I would like to divide the first DataFrame by the second, in the following way:

```
     info_1  info_2
key                
A     1       6
B     0.286   1
C     1       2.667
D     0.444   1
E     1       0
```

that is:

```
     info_1  info_2
key                
A       1/1     6/1
B       2/7     7/7
C       3/3     8/3
D       4/9     9/9
E       5/5     0/5
```

How can I do this work without iterate over each element with a for-cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `div` with `axis=0`

```
df1.div(df2['info_3'], axis=0)
```

---

```
       info_1    info_2
key                    
A    1.000000  6.000000
B    0.285714  1.000000
C    1.000000  2.666667
D    0.444444  1.000000
E    1.000000  0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

use the *div* method

```
df1.div(df2['info_3'], axis=0)
```

you can check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-div/) as tutorial with examples

Comment: With the suggested statement, the result is:

<code>
   A   B   C   D   E  info_1  info_2
key                                    
A   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
B   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
C   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
D   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
E   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
</code>

Comment: true. I forgot to add axis=0 to the div. I corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for me (pandas 0.25), `axis=0` is needed for `div`:

```
df1.div(df2.info_3, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
       info_1    info_2
key                    
A    1.000000  6.000000
B    0.285714  1.000000
C    1.000000  2.666667
D    0.444444  1.000000
E    1.000000  0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas comes with a `div` function [See documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)

In your case you can use it as: `df1.div(df2['info_3'])`